# Texmaker portable with Miktex portable

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I am trying to setup texmaker portable to work with Miktex portable. I found instructions here: http://jimstitzel.com/2010/01/configuring-texmaker-usb-with-miktex-portable/.

Updating of Miktex doesn't seem to work for me since it keeps searching for packages, so I skipped that step since I didn't think it was necessary. Also, I did not add the tikz files and change the ghostscript and r directories etc since I don't use them anyway.

So the only thing I really changed was to change the directories in texmaker to these:

> LaTeX: "../MiKTeX/miktex/bin/latex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
>
> PdfLaTeX: "../MiKTeX/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
>
> XeLaTeX: "../MiKTeX/miktex/bin/xelatex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
>
> LuaLaTeX: "../MiKTeX/miktex/bin/lualatex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
>
> Latexmk: "../MiKTeX/miktex/bin/latexmk.exe" -e "$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode/" -pdf %.tex
>
> Bib(la)tex: "../MiKTeX/miktex/bin/bibtex.exe" %
>
> Makeindex: "../MiKTeX/miktex/bin/makeindex.exe" %.idx
>
> dvips: "../MiKTeX/miktex/bin/dvips.exe" -o %.ps %.dvi
>
> Dvipdfm: "../MiKTeX/miktex/bin/dvipdfm.exe" %.dvi
>
> ps2pdf: "../MiKTeX/miktex/bin/ps2pdf.exe" %.ps
>
> metapost: "../MiKTeX/bin/mpost.exe" --interaction nonstopmode
>
> Dvi Viewer: "../MiKTeX/miktex/bin/yap.exe" -1 -s @%.tex %.dvi

However, whenever I compile I get the error that Texmaker "could not start the command" for pdflatex. What could be the issue here?

Also, on a sidenote, I noticed that whenever I execute texmaker from a different computer, the settings are lost. I know I can save them and load them each time, but is there no way to do this quicker?

Comment: maybe you should specify full path rather than relative path

Comment: @bdeonovic well it wouldn't really be portable at that point :)